# Trouble removing extra hyphens from string in python?

Tags: python, string

```
def checkio(line):
   list.remove(max("---"))
   list.remove(min("--"))
   return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio('I---like--python') == "I-like-python", 'Example'
```

$ I am trying to remove the "---" and the "--" from the string I like python and it does nto seem to be working. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a new user please take time to read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it will help you get acquainted here, and you will get your first badge!

Comment: What's the `max('---')` supposed to mean? Does this mean you want to fix `'---'`, but leave `'----'` and longer such substrings alone?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want `list.remove()` here. This removed an item from a list. In fact, you don't have a list at all.

`max()` can be used, but all it does is just returns one dash.

Looks like a job for regular expressions:

```
import re
def checkio(line):
    reutrn re.sub(r'(-)+', r'\1', line)
```

When testing:

```
>>> checkio('I---like--python') == "I-like-python"
True
```

Remember that in python, strings are *immutable*, so your code would have no effect if `list.remove` modified the string. `re.sub` does not modify the string in place, but returns the replaced string, so we have to assign it to a variable (or, in this case, just return it).

Comment: @user2640086 Does an error appear? Or is it another example that doesn't work?

Comment: NameError: global name 's' is not defined, checkio, 10. I am doing this not in a compiler but an online coding game that helps me learn python for development

Comment: @user2640086 Oops, that was my fault. Let me fix it

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions for that:

```
>>> import re
>>> source = "String-----with-hyphens-nohypenshere--morehyphenshere-----------"
>>> string = re.sub(r'-+', '-', source)
>>> string
'String-with-hyphens-nohypenshere-morehyphenshere-'
```

Using regex in this way you can identify and replace with ^^ O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to replace each `---` with `-`, and replace each `--` into `-`… that's easy to translate directly into Python:

```
def checkio(line):
    return line.replace('---', '-').replace('--', '-')
```

(If you want to fix replace *any* string of two or more `-` characters with a single `-`, whether there are 2, 3, or 45, then it's a job for regular expressions. But otherwise, you're just making the problem more complicated. You don't want to just use "magic code" you don't understand—and, while it's definitely worth learning regular expressions at some point, you don't have to learn them to solve this problem.)